# Почему не удаляются интервалы clearInterval()?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, javascript-events, clearinterval

[Тут код](https://codesandbox.io/s/xlkmjl0z7o?hidenavigation=1)

В эдиторе кода над результатом есть кнопка показать в отдельном окне. нажмите, так будет всё виднее и понятнее. (+ в эдиторе анимация иногда лагает)

Итак, тут всё просто: есть 3д куб. Крутить его можно с помощью нумпада. (<kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>8</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>). Если зажать кнопку (`onkeydown`) - запускается интервал, который постоянно меняет `rotateY` и `rotateX` куба. Как только кнопка отпускается (`onkeyup`) - интервал удаляется с помощью функции `clearInterval()`. Если держать кнопку чуть больше секунды - анимация зависает, начинает дергаться как чёрт и не может остановиться, когда кнопку отпустили. То же самое происходит, если зажать хоть на мгновение 2 кнопки сразу.

Вероятнее всего я просто не до конца понимаю, как работают интервалы или событие `onkeydown`.

Подскажите, как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нажатая кнопка генерит множественные события `onkeydown`. Это первое.

Второе. Код, который использует одну и ту же переменную для многократного создания таймеров, должен обнулять эту переменную после вызова `clearInterval`, чтобы иметь возможность в любой момент выяснить, запущен какой-нибудь таймер или нет.

```
window.onkeyup = function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = null;
}
var rotate = {
  right: function() {
    if (!interval) {
      interval = setInterval(function() {
        rotateY += 2;
        document.querySelector(".cube").style.transform = "rotateX(" + rotateX + "deg) rotateY(" + rotateY + "deg)";
      }, 10);
    }
  },
```